# Apache2 Website Won't Change Default URL When Navigating Throughout the Site

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, phpbb

**Good Day**

I've recently setup my new webserver on Linux with the typical LAMP system. I am using PhPBB as the base for my website.

Everything is online and accessible from outside the network.

The only issue:  the URL will never change from www.gaymerscommunity.com. You can navigate throughout the test forums, register section, or any other part of the website and it will always just stay that same URL, no /index /forums /register or anything. Always just the base URL.

I enabled rewrite with a2enmod, and I allowed override all on the directory in apache2.conf; I also changed the /etc/hosts file early on to include '127.0.0.1 gaymerscommunity.com'.

Everything else is pretty much default.

I would really like for each post on the forum to have a unique url, or at least each forum to have a url that I could use to direct people to appropriate content.

Where should I start?

I do have a .htaccess file in the root of my folder, but I got it from someone that said it was their PhPBB default .htaccess file. So, I just copied it over and enabled rewrite.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

#
# Uncomment the statement below if you want to make use of
# HTTP authentication and it does not already work.
# This could be required if you are for example using PHP via Apache CGI.
#
#RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

#
# The following 3 lines will rewrite URLs passed through the front controller
# to not require app.php in the actual URL. In other words, a controller is
# by default accessed at /app.php/my/controller, but can also be accessed at
# /my/controller
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]

#
# If symbolic links are not already being followed,
# uncomment the line below.
# http://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2008/06/10/mod_rewrite-forbidden-403-with-apache-228/
#
#Options +FollowSymLinks
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_version.c>
<IfVersion < 2.4>
    <Files "config.php">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from All
    </Files>
    <Files "common.php">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from All
    </Files>
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
    <Files "config.php">
        Require all denied
    </Files>
    <Files "common.php">
        Require all denied
    </Files>
</IfVersion>
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_version.c>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    <Files "config.php">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from All
    </Files>
    <Files "common.php">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from All
    </Files>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    <Files "config.php">
        Require all denied
    </Files>
    <Files "common.php">
        Require all denied
    </Files>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have the correct .htaccess file in your web root directory of this website?

Comment: I do have a .htaccess in the root, but I'm not sure if it is setup properly. I found another user that said this was his default, and I copied that over to use as my own.

Comment: I included that .htaccess file in my original post.

Comment: The syntax of .htaccess file may vary depending on the Apache's version. Check with your friend if you both have same version/release of Apache.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed**

Turns out it wasn't anything to do with my own server setup, at least not on my server's end. I clicked a link on the website and selected to 'open in new tab.' Behold, there was a new URL address. The only issue... it was listed as http:///forums.

So, I went to my domain provider. I contacted them recently to ask them how to set this all up, and they configured the domain to forward to my public ip address. Turns out that was wrong.

Do NOT forward your domain to the public ip address. Instead, edit your DNS 'Type A' listing with the name '@' to point to your public ip address.

The more you know =)